# Chrome issue -Unknown things on my screen

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Whenever i open a site, contents of other sites are displayed on the webpage as well which causes lagging of that site.

Whenever I open any site, the contents of the site 'gogoanime.com' are displayed on screen.

I tried right clicking and clicking on inspect element but some source and local storage bar opened and i didn't understand a thing! I even deleted cookies a hundred times! This is irritating. Anyone please help me if you can.

I could upload a screenshot but i don't know how to upload one!

Comment: Have you tried running malware/virus scans to rule that option out? Normally when you are having weird problems like that with Web-Pages, it is due to Browser Hijacking. MalwareBytes is a great tool for malware/hijacking scanning

Comment: Take a look at [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/a/512901/97028).

Comment: To upload a screenshot, press `Print SCRN` or similar and paste it into MSPAINT and save

Comment: Thnx alot even though i got no help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you have malware on your computer. See CharlieRB's comment on how to remove it. It's not the fault of the browser.